# Preg_match a certain URL - PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have countless URL's that look like this **(1)**, and some that look like this **(2)**:

1) `http://URL.com/gallery/image.png`

2) `http://URL.com/gallery/#/image.png`

*Where # represents a numbered folder.*

I'd like to add `thumb_` into the URL so it looks like this:

1) `http://URL.com/gallery/thumb_image.png`

2) `http://URL.com/gallery/#/thumb_image.png`

How would I do this?

One thing to consider is that the folder before the image file can be any number, and the image file isn't always named "image.png". I did that as an example.

Comment: So you want web server rewrite rules, or actually rename the files programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple regex like this:

```
(\w+\.\w+)$
```

With a replacement string:

```
thumb_\1
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/3f4guD/2)**

Php code

```
$re = '/(\w+\.\w+$)/m';
$str = 'http://URL.com/gallery/image.png
http://URL.com/gallery/#/image.png';
$subst = 'thumb_\\1';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use preg_replace function

```
<?PHP
$input_lines="http://URL.com/gallery/#/image.png";
ECHO preg_replace("/\w+\.\w+$/", "thumb_$0", $input_lines);
?>
```